# Pandas save CSV ZIP with proper internal name

Tags: pandas, zip

I'm running on Pandas 0.23.4.

I have a DataFrame called `df`. On it, I invoke:

```
df.to_csv('name.csv.zip', compression='zip')
```

This creates a zip file called `name.csv.zip`. Inside it, however, the CSV file is called `name.csv.zip` and not `name.csv`. How can I correct this?

Comment: df.to_csv('name.csv.zip') should be df.to_csv('name.csv'), no?

Comment: Actually, maybe no because it is preferred to have zip'd archives be called something.zip with the archive members having the original uncompressed name.

Comment: If I renamed it to `name.csv` then I would have a ZIP file masquerading as a CSV file and when anyone else would want to open it, they can't.

Answer (score 0):

In pandas 0.24, there is a new `to_csv` keyword `compression='infer'` which will look at the suffix of the file being saved.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work that great with zip archives, because the name of the file being saved is used as the name of the member of the zip archive.  And it is unclear how to provide archive member names.  So what happens is you get the `replace df.csv.zip? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll, [N]one, [r]ename:` on extraction and would be left to rename the members of the archive.  This also happens when `infer` is not used and a name and compression method of zip is instead used.

saving df.csv with compression zip gives df.csv with df.csv in it - the archive does not get a .zip suffix.  Can be annoying to someone trying to use the file.

saving df.csv.zip with compression zip gives df.csv.zip with df.csv.zip as the archive member name. Can be annoying when extracting, because there is then an archive/member name collision.

Yet a zip archive can be constructed with proper zip archive member names.

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile as zf
from pandas.compat import StringIO

print(pd.__version__)

csvdata = StringIO("""index,id1,id2,timestamp,number
465,255,3644,2019-05-02 08:00:20.137000,123123
62,87,912,2019-05-02 5:00:00,435456
""")

# prep dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(csvdata, sep=",")

with zf.ZipFile('archive.zip', 'w') as myziparchive:
    myziparchive.writestr('df.csv', df.to_csv())
```

```
file archive.zip 
archive.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
Richs-MBP:pandas_examples randrews$ zip --show-files archive.zip 
Archive contains:
  df.csv
Total 1 entries (119 bytes)
```

And more than on dataframe can be placed inside.